# imported maven project in eclipse but showing error while running

Tags: jquery, maven, import

I am very new to maven.

As i import a maven project from my friend and try running it it, it shows an error like `The archive: E:/jquery-3.5.1.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.`.

It is a complete maven project and I am unable to run it.

[image: Snaphot]

Comment: check if your `pom.xml` has dependency for jquery jar

Answer (score 0):

if your pom doesn't have jquery in dependencies, add this to dependencies and run `mvn install` which should download the jquery jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```